# Do Water Parks boost Golf Courses the same way Entertainment Complexes do?

Tags: civilization-6

Entertainment Complex grants +1 culture adjacency bonus to Golf Courses.  Water Parks are very similar to Entertainment Complexes.  I don't see anywhere that explicitly states Water Parks grant Golf Courses +1 culture adjacency bonus.

Comment: Could you test it out?

Comment: I would if it were an urgent question.  No one is obligated to answer if the question is too much trouble.  I covet every minute of free time I have at the PC.